# Finding the RMS over all time of a difficult function

Tags: limits, trigonometry, definite-integrals, exponential-function, mathematical-physics

Well, I've to find the [RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) (root mean square) over all time of the following function:

[image]

In the picture I plotted a case where I used values for components in the [full bridge rectifier with capacitor filter](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode23.gif) but I want to solve the general case.

From $0\le t\le\frac{1}{4f}$ the function that describes the waveform is:

$$\left|u\sin\left(2\pi ft\right)\right|\tag1$$

When the sine wave is at its top, the function turn into a exponential function (because the capacitor discharges):

$$u\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\tau}\right)\tag2$$

The point where the sine wave returns is:

$$\left|u\sin\left(2\pi ft\right)\right|=u\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\tau}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space t:=T=\dots\tag3$$

Where $\frac{1}{2f}<T<\frac{3}{4f}$

And then the proces starts over again: the exponential function comes back when the sine wave is at its top.

> Now, I need to find the RMS over all time so I wrote:

$$\lim_{\text{n}\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\text{n}}\int_0^\text{n}\left(\text{y}\left(t\right)\right)^2\space\text{d}t}\tag4$$

And in order to find $\int_0^\text{n}\left(\text{y}\left(t\right)\right)^2\space\text{d}t$ I wrote:

$$\int_0^\text{n}\left(\text{y}\left(t\right)\right)^2\space\text{d}t\stackrel{?}{=}\int_0^\frac{1}{4f}\left(\left|u\sin\left(2\pi ft\right)\right|\right)^2\space\text{d}t+\text{n}\cdot\int_0^T\left(u\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\tau}\right)\right)^2\space\text{d}t+\text{n}\cdot\int_T^\frac{3}{4f}\left(\left|u\sin\left(2\pi ft\right)\right|\right)^2\space\text{d}t\tag5$$

> The question is, am I right and how do I proceed?

Comment: what is the RMS?

Comment: @uniquesolution Root Mean Square, see my edit.

Comment: It should suffice to calculate the RMS over a single period (the transient phenomenon at the beginning does not matter), which should be write-able as a sum of two integrals: one where the integrand is the square of the sine, one where the integrand is the square of the exponential.

Comment: what is the function $y$?

Comment: @Wouter I can't skip the transient phenomenon

Comment: @jan: why not ?

Comment: @jan Yes you can. If you truly take the $n\rightarrow\infty$ limit, the contribution of the transient phenomenon is zero.

Comment: @Wouter Can you show me the procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating an integral
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n y(t)^2 dt}$$
But your $y(t)$ is periodic aside from a transient phenomenon
$$y(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}y_{\text{transient}}(t) & t <T_0 \\ y_{\text{periodic}}(t-T_0) & T_0<t<T_0+P  \\ y_{\text{periodic}}(t-(T_0+P)) & T_0+P<t<T_0+2P \\ \vdots\end{matrix}\right.$$
So the original integral becomes
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n y(t)^2 dt}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{\underbrace{\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{T_0} y_{\text{transient}}(t)^2 dt}_{\rightarrow 0\text{ as }n\rightarrow\infty} + \frac{1}{n}\int_{T_0}^{n} y(t)^2 dt}$$
what remains is periodic.

Comment: And $T_0$ is my equation $\left(3\right)$?

Comment: Yes. (but note that your eq. (2) probably needs a temporal translation, if you want it to equal the sine at its peak)

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by that?!

Comment: You don't want $u\exp(-t/\tau)$ but $u\exp(-(t-t_{peak})/\tau)$ where $t_{peak}$ is the time where your sine peaks. otherwise your function is discontinuous.

Comment: I see, but how can the last existing integral be rewritten using this? Or must I ask is my equation $\left(5\right)$ right?

Comment: I don't think your (5) is right, I don't see where the multiplications by $n$ come from.